# Passing selectors as function parameters in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

[Fiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/vytw3q3z/8/)

Can I pass selectors other than $(this) selector as function parameters?

What I mean is that the selectors (`#Aarea` and `Barea`) I want to pass are the ones that I want to append some HTML content to.

```
function info(a){
  var source = $(this).data('source')
  $(a).html(source)
  console.log(source);
}

$('#one').click(info('#Aarea'))
$('#two').click(info('#Barea'))

<button data-source="AAA" id='one'>Button</button>
<div id="Aarea"></div>
<div id='Barea'></div>
<a href='#' data-source='BBB' id='two'>Click</a>
```

But it doesn't work unless I don't use the parameters and specify those selectors in the function.

Comment: `$(this)` isn't a selector.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

What your code:

```
$('#one').click(info('#Aarea'))
```

...is doing is **calling** `info` and passing its return value into `click`, exactly like `foo(bar())` *calls* `bar` and passes its return value into `foo`.

What you want to give `click` is a function to call. In your case, the simplest way is to use a wrapper function:

```
$('#one').click(function() {
    info(this, '#Aarea');
});
```

...and update `info` to accept the element as an argument:

```
function info(element, a){
  var source = $(element).data('source')
  $(a).html(source)
  console.log(source);
}
```

[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vytw3q3z/13/)

Alternately, you can use `Function#call` to call your original `info` without changing it:

```
$('#one').click(function() {
    info.call(this, '#Aarea');
});
```

`Function#call` calls a function, setting `this` during the function call to the first argument you give it (and then passing along any other arguments you give to it).

[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vytw3q3z/14/)

Answer (score 2):

I think your problem is that you're passing the evaluated function into your click handler.

The proper format is something more like this:

```
$('#one').click(function(){ info('#Aarea'); })
$('#two').click(function(){ info('#Barea'); })
```

Here's a fiddle with working code -http://jsfiddle.net/2548hkvg/

Alternatively, you could define the target area as a data attribute as well, and only have one  function, seen in this fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/k42ahykb/

In the code for that, we're defining info as our function expression that we pass to the click handler, and `this` is properly retained.

```
function info(e){
  var source = $(this).data('source');
  var target = $(this).data('target');
  $(target).html(source)
  console.log(source);
}

$('#one').click(info)
$('#two').click(info)
```

Comment: That fails because you don't preserve `this`.

Answer (score 2):

```
$('#one').click(info('#Aarea'))
```

You are calling the function here, so the result passed to `.click()` is `undefined`. Like @iabw said, you need to wrap it in a function expression so the click event can invoke `info()` successfully.

Answer (score 1):

Just passthrough this from onclick function to info.

```
$('#one').click(function(){ info.call(this, '#Aarea'); })
$('#two').click(function(){ info.call(this, '#Barea'); })
```